# Get Highcharts Series Data after Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am trying to get the series data from a Highcharts chart once it has been called and loaded to the page.

So far I've only been successful in getting a bunch of strings that isn't what I am after obviously. Wonder if someone can help me with this one.

jQuery Code:

```
success: function (chartData) {
    if(chart != undefined) {
        $('#meterloader').hide();
        $.each(chart.series[0], function(value) {
            alert(value);
        });
    } else {
        $('#meterloader').hide();
        $('#meterbox').html("<div><p class='textcentre bold red'>There was an error loading the chart.</p></div>");
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

you need plotted data from the chart,
then try

```
chart.series[0].data
```

if you need all the options from series then try

```
chart.series
```

this will return the entire series structure of the chart.

I hope this is useful for you.

Comment: It's better to use `series.options.data` instead of `series.data`, because the latter may not contain all the points. See [these comments in the Highcharts code](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/master/js/parts/Series.js#L5-L9) for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: In my comment above, `series = chart.series[0]` or any other series you want.

Comment: Thanks, this worked fine for static/single series, but I have a strange "animated series", which have data which "change" 40 times upon clicking/animating a slider: https://www.dep.lazio.it/covid/covid_map.php  (last map, which is chart n. 1). I looked around in all series and options arrays and subarrays, but I can't find any array around 40 elements in size which can contain all the series.