# Get series data from highchart after chart loaded / displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

How to get the series data from loaded highchart, I want to retrieve on another method.

Loading highchart :

HTML :

```
<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px"></div>
```

JS :

```
function generateHighchart(){

  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Fruit Consumption'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Fruit eaten'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [1, 0, 4]},
    {
        name: 'John',
        data: [5, 7, 3]}]
   });
}

function getSeriqalData(){
    var Myseries = // how to retrieve series data here for using some other purpose 
}
```

I have refereed this link but retrieving on same function itself 
    [Get Highcharts Series Data after Load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18840397/get-highcharts-series-data-after-load)

I am generating 2 to 5 charts dynamically, after loaded the charts i want to reuse that series value for another purpose.

Comment: And what is wrong with above question&answer? To get series data use `chart.series[index].data` or `chart.series[index].userOptions.data`. Or just store copy of data used for Highcharts before rendering chart.

Comment: It is much easier to establish the data as a separate variable first, and then use the variable to load the chart, and for whatever other purpose you need to: http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/3qtZr/17/

Comment: I can use the variable, after loaded i want to get the average value of all series value based on one button click. How to do that even i store it on a variable? In case if i want to do for n number of chart?

Comment: You can iterate on each serie (chart.series array), get points and  calculate your average.

Comment: @SebastianBochan If its before load by using the chart variable i can do all the stuff, but after load how to get it from chart?

Comment: In the callback, you have access to series by chart.series array. Each of series has reference to point arrays (data field). Last step is extract these points, calculate your new serie and use chart.addSeries()